# magnifier for HTML document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I have a page and I want to create a magnifier for my web page *(HTML document not just images)*, I want do this for some reasons and I just want to know **How can I do it?  and is this possible?**

> Nothing is impossible, the word itself says " I'm possible"!  **Audery Hepburn**

I know it's possible for professional programmers, and I'm just asking from **them, How to do it?**

I need **lens magnifier** and for all document, something like **[Windows magnifier](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf-JAVA/Doc/images/823/c03671284.jpg)**

I **searched**  on the Internet but there are just magnifiers for Images, and I need magnifier for all HTML document, and I don't expect you do it for me, I know JavaScript programming and I just need your suggestions and helps to find a way.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. Unfortunately stack overflow doesn't quite work this way. you are expected to do your own research and to design and write your own code. We'll help you if you get stuck on something specific, but we aren't going to tell you how. That said, I agree - it's quite possible... but you will need to use the magic of the internet to do a bit of research to find out how others have done it. If you get stuck on a particular issue, then come back and we;ll help you get past that. Good luck!

Comment: @AdriánBolonio Please read all my question not a part of it, I said I want magnifier for HTML document structure not for Images. All of that libraries are for Images...

Comment: Is that what you're looking for? http://jaukia.github.io/zoomooz/

Comment: @AdriánBolonio yeah something like that... Thanks

Comment: @AdriánBolonio post your comment as answer, and LASH mark that answer as answered :). Thanks

Comment: You can use magnifier addon "https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/magnifier/" of firefox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look to **Zoomooz**. "It is a jQuery plugin for making web page elements zoom. It can be used for making Prezi like slideshows and for zooming to images or other details. Zoomooz is an easy-to-use jQuery plugin for making any web page element zoom."

Source:

http://jaukia.github.io/zoomooz/

https://github.com/jaukia/zoomooz

https://github.com/m-kermani/magni

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. Links rot easily.

Comment: I know, but he was looking some plugin, but unfortunately I cannot copy the whole library, so I left the link to the library and GitHub. Sorry for the incovenience.

Comment: This is one of the reasons why [asking for a library is off-topic on SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254394/1014587).

Comment: @Mast I just said I need a way to find how to create my own library, and this answer really helped me. Thanks

Comment: @Mast I've tried to make a more elaborated answer, so it's not just links :)

Comment: @AdriánBolonio Much better, upvoted.

Comment: I found a very good plugin on github https://github.com/MohammadKermani/magni